# In Aura Component,Can I Call a local method in toast?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, toast

a.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    //...
    <lightning:button label="looks" onclick="{!c.initDialog}" />
    //...
</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
initDialog: function (component, event, helper) {
  //doSomething
},
doSomething: function (component, event, helper) {
   ....//doSomething1
   var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        type: 'info',
                        message: 'This is a required message',
                        messageTemplate: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX{0}',
                        messageTemplateData: [{
                            url: '{!c.initDialog}',//here,I can call initDialog function!
                            label: 'here'
                        }]
                    });
                    toastEvent.fire();
   ....//doSomething2
}
```

In toast,Can i call "initDialog" function?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can generate a url to another component (see [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation)), but you can't generate a method call somehow.